# How to delete Firefox plugins?

Tags: firefox, gmail

Today I found the Firefox plugins maybe cause Gmail freeze after you click the new emails.

After change all Firefox plugins to "Never activate", then this issue resolved.
So I wish to delete everything rather than keep the "disabled" items there.

But how can I clean up everything there?

Since so many plugins there, I have no time to check it one by one but wish to clean everything to get a fresh Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make a real difference if you're deleting the unwanted plugins too. When they are deactivated and Firefox runs fine -- it's fine.

The file size savings on disc by deleting them are --compared to savings from deleting for example obsolete tmp files-- negligibly.

But to answer your question:
Location of plugins folder depends on which Operating System you're on. The page `about:plugins` shows the full path to every single plugin file (they can be in lots of different folders depending on the software you have installed). On Windows for example you'd be facing file paths like

```
C:\Users\foo_bar\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\plugins\npgoogletalk.dll
```

for Google Talk plugin

You have to have administrator rights and delete *all the listed* files in every of those locations.

Comment: Great, I am working on MacOSx. and after delete everything at:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins and $HOME/Library/Internet Plug-Ins, then it's clean now! It's a so long issue confused with me for Gmail access. wish it helpful for others!